# How do the latest measurements of the Hubble expansion match the QFT prediction?

Tags: cosmology

From what I read the expansion of the universe predicted by QFT is said to be [the worst theoretical prediction in the history of physics](https://www.space.com/38911-worst-theoretical-prediction-physics-history.html).

There is also lots of buzz in the astronomy press about the [latest Hubble expansion measurements](https://www.nasa.gov/feature/goddard/2019/new-hubble-constant-measurement-adds-to-mystery-of-universe-s-expansion-rate) being askew from predicted values.

Does the new crisis in the Hubble constant measurement refer to the QFT prediction or something else? Perhaps the crisis refers to discrepencies in more than one way to measure the constant and not more than one way to predict.

Comment: Shouldn't this be asked on Physics SE? We have a 10-15 year cutoff convention between recent events and history. The problem is called "Hubble tension" (between Planck satellite and Hubble telescope data, assuming the standard [ΛCDM model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda-CDM_model)), and is actively discussed. Here is a recent paper on it, [Relieving the Hubble Tension with Primordial Magnetic Fields](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/33196251/).

Comment: The [Hubble tension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubble's_law#Measured_values_of_the_Hubble_constant) (which the recent articles are about) is unrelated to the [cosmological constant problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmological_constant_problem) (which is the "worst prediction in the history of physics").

Comment: @benrg ....thank you and Conifold for clearing this up for me. They are not the same problems and also for clarifying the rules of "history"  stack exchange. This will be useful for me in the future. The comments  answered the question I was wondering. .Thx.